# Submit a "pure" HTTP request from HTML page

Tags: html, http

I need to send the following HTTP request to my REST server from an HTML page to retrieve another page. How to do that using javascript or forms or links or whatever ?

Note that the HTTP request body must contain plain text with no key/value pairs as a form usually does.

```
PUT /somerequest HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myhost.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml

Payload of the request to be read by the server script.
The script will return a HTML content to my browser.
Thanks !
```

Comment: I tried a form without specifying a "name" attribute for the input tag holding the HTTP request payload and setting the "action" attribute to "put". I cannot use XMLHttpRequest as what I request is another HTTP ressource (another HTML page)...

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I'm sure you will find what you want there.

And if you don't look at a lower layer: XMLHttpRequest

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately XMLHttpRequest does not seem to be the solution as what I request is another HTTP ressource (another HTML page)...

Comment: I don't know anything that could do that, but if you can't do it from client side, do it from server side, send an ajax request to your server and then use PHP an curl(or something else) to dial the other server.